# Check If Email Exist in DB and if Exist Send Email for Reset Password with hash code Yii2 Basic

Tags: yii2

My login is with email only instead of username , and when I click on forgotten password "link" and type some email address to check if that email address exist in the DB,and if exist to send email to that email address . I make the forgotten form ,but dont know how to make the rest ,because I`m a bit new in Yii2 Basic

my DB is with fields id(AI),email,password,firstname,secondname (if someone need this)

Comment: You can refer `Yii2 Advanced Application` https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

Comment: `Yii2 Advanced Application`  basically provide user login, forgot password and reset password. I think this one can help you.

Comment: sure but some things are different and I got some errors,and dont know where to look for those errors... I already try to took some things from there but...

Comment: put your errors and related all code. i sure to get your problem solution in `stackoverflow`.

Comment: in the PasswordResetRequestForm I have problems with  Sends an email with a link, for resetting the password. dont have field exists,and I log only email,dont have username nowhere :D  also got errors on findOne and dont have "exist" in my db

Comment: please give your **common->models->User** function code for `function findByUsername($username, $userType = NULL)`

Comment: public static function findByUsername($username) {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117674/discussion-between-vishu-and-ross).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Sending Email to someone worked: in SiteController**

```
public function actionForgot() {
    $model = new ForgotForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        if ($model->sendEmail($model->email)) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions');
            return $this->goHome();
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry,we are unable to reset your password for email provided');
        }
    }
    return $this->render('forgot', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

**and in ForgotForm :**

```
public function sendEmail() {
    $token = substr(base64_encode(sha1(mt_rand())), 0, 64);

    $model = LoginUser::find()->where(['email' => $this->email])->one();

    $model->setAttributes([
        'token' => $token
    ]);
    if ($model->save()) {
        $mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('redirect')
                ->setFrom('rosensoul@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($model->email)
                ->setSubject('Message subject');

    }
}
```

Comment: please give your `ForgotForm` model